# MFT NAudio Resampling on the fly

Tags: naudio, ms-media-foundation, resampling

I want to resample an audio file using NAudio and MFT on-the-fly.

For example, I have the following audio file:

File name: MyAudioFile.mp3

Duration: 10 sec

When this file is being played, I only want to resample that particular position to WAV in the desired format.

So, if the length of "MyAudioFile.mp3" is 10 sec, and the "current play position" is 2.5 sec, I want to resample ***only*** that portion of data into WAV format at the sampling rate of 48 KHz.

When the audio progresses further, again, only the "current play position" must be resampled.

I tried the following code:

```
    WaveStream reader = new MediaFoundationReaderRT([path of 
    "MyAudioFile.mp3"]);

    MemoryStream outMemStream = new MemoryStream(); //Decode to memory 
    stream

    using (reader)
    using (var resampler = new MediaFoundationResampler(reader, 
    resampler.WaveFormat))
    {
        WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(outMemStream, resampler);
        rsws = new RawSourceWaveStream(outMemStream, resampler.WaveFormat);
    }

    WaveChannel32 waveformInputStream = new WaveChannel32(rsws);
```

The resampling happens properly; however it resamples the whole audio file, which takes time.

What I am looking at is just resampling the "current play position" of the audio, and discard any other position information.

Thanks! Appreciate if you can provide some sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resample on the fly, just pass the reader directly into `MediaFoundationResampler`. You will now have an `ISampleProvider` so you won't be able to use `WaveChannel32`, but really that is an obsolete class now, and you should be able to do anything you need with other `ISampleProvider` classes from NAudio.